# POST to a nested resource using ng-admin

Tags: ng-admin

The documentation shows an [example](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/API-mapping.md#nested-relationships-urls) on how to fetch entities on a nested resource (`http://[baseApiUrl]/posts/123/comments`) by using an interceptor on the `$http` Angular service.
I'd like to know how to create entities on nested resources. Is this possible on ng-admin without resorting to custom pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this some time and found a work around. I've also tried your interceptor to fetch child objects of some parent object. It works. But I went back to the embedded_list to make also creation and updating of the parent with the child object in one post/put to the backend. So when fetching /posts/123 I also have the comments in the object. Then, after changing some data I PUT the whole object back. That works. There are some problems however. One of them is that 'reference' field types ***within*** the embedded_list don't populate properly. You can work around this by adding the same reference field to the editionView() or creationView() (the level above the embedded_list and set label to '' and cssClasses to 'visibility: hidden'. A very bad solution of course but it does work. I still need to ask this to the developers of ng-admin.

So I now try to use embedded_list as much as possible to be able to put and post objects with child elements in one call to the backend.

Does this help?